# adding filter to web.xml in grails

Tags: grails

I have to add [urlrewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) fitler to my web.xml

I am not able to find any easy way that will add the below filter

```
    <urlrewrite>
        <rule>
            <name>seo redirect</name>
            <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^www.example.com</condition>
            <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^localhost</condition>
            <from>^/(.*)</from>
            <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">http://www.example.com/$1</to>
        </rule> 
</urlrewrite>
```

I am using 2.4.2 . I looked at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html but not sure if i can add this filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the `install-templates` command and edit the `web.xml` once it's copied to the `src/templates/war` directory. Quick and easy.